# WebView : WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING : Below Android 4.4?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-view

Is there backward compatibility for `WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING` property of webview's settings (Introduced in API level 19)? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html) 
I tried this (https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview/tree/master/src/org/chromium/android_webview) but not useful.

I need `WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING` above 4.0 API level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TEXT_AUTOSIZING was added in the KitKat WebView and would be rather hard to emulate in earlier versions. You could try [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org), although it doesn't look like they expose this as a setting so it depends on which layout algorithm is set as their default.

Comment: Actually in my native android app, HTML contents (plain text htmls, inline images htmls etc) are looking fine with **TEXT_AUTOSIZING** property. **TEXT_AUTOSIZING** is auto adjust (In readable format) plain text htmls even if I zoom out webview. Can I achieve this using **'Crossswalk'** ?

Comment: @user1046105 Like I said - I don't know whether Crosswalk has TEXT_AUTOSIZING or not. I do know that Crosswalk is compatible with Android versions earlier than KitKat which is why I suggested it in the first place.

Comment: Okay, I will try and let you know. Thanks Marcin.