# Scale WebView images only to fit screen android

Tags: android, webview

I have view with ImageView, TextView and WebView.  View xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/article_details_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_details_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_details_image_view"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_details_author_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_details_title_text_view"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_details_date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_details_author_text_view"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/article_details_body_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_details_date_text_view"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

WebView gets html body from string that I get from blog. It shows text fine but images is too big and I can scroll WebView horizontaly. 
I've tried to use:

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

But nothing happens and I've tried:

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

It does scales images from HTML to perfect size, but scales text too and text size becomes very small. How should I get same text size but scaled images?

How it looks in app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0yv2.jpg

How it looks in HTML:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFVkE.jpg

Comment: you need to add some style to your html, for example     `img{display: inline; height: auto; max-width: 100%;}`

Comment: I've used your example and set max-width to device display width and it's worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will help you to solve this problem partially. 
Have you heard about **WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING** which is introduced
in Android API level 19. This will solve your problem for text as well as images in webview. For android version 4.4 and above its working fine.

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
```

For below versions there is no perfect  solution yet I found. Please check below discussion.

[WebView : WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING : Below Andoird 4.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248081/webview-websettings-layoutalgorithm-text-autosizing-below-andoird-4-4)

Also you can use **webSettings.setDefaultFontSize((int)fontSize);** method to manage your text size in webview. Hope this will help you.

Comment: It did not change anything. Do I need to change my XML?

Comment: Roo, I have updated my answer please try **webSettings.setDefaultFontSize((int)fontSize)** method also.